# Laravel if model has attribute check against auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I have an Laravel 5.4 application where the auth user belongs to a company,
this is set in the `user->company_id`.

Some other models also have a company_id so different users from the same company can **access**/**view**/**edit** these records.

In my routes i currently use resource routes so how can i check in a general way if the auth user can access the index, `show`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy` methods from the corresponding controllers?

Comment: I would suggest you read the following Laravel docs on [Authorisation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a method in all of the models that have the company_id on it:

```
public function isOwnedBy($companyId)
{
   return $this->company_id == $companyId ? true : false;
}
```

And then, whenever you want to edit, show ... that model, you simply call this method before you do that. Let's say you have a page with the field "company_id".

```
$page = Page::first(); // just some random page

if(!$page->isOwnedBy(\Auth::user()->company_id))
    // throw an exception or do something that the user can't continue
```